# How to maintain session in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, session, angularjs-scope

I am just exploring AngularJs and comes to a point where i need to maintain user session like if login then redirect it to home page else keep user to login Page.

The two techniques which i discovered for this purpose is to use `web browser local storage or session storage`.

My web application is user based, such that if user closes the browser its session must be killed. So that next time when it open browser it must singin.

This could not be achieved by using `localstorage` because it will be availalbe for next time.

Currently, i am using `sessionstorage` but the problem is that if tab is close or user open `navigation` in a new tab the current session is not available.

So how do i maintain session for a user unless and untill it closes the browser.

My implementation is as:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.storedInfo) {
            $rootScope.loginUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.storedInfo);
        } else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('storedInfo', JSON.stringify($rootScope.loginUser));
        }

    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }

    if ($rootScope.loginUser.loginTrue) {
        $location.path('/home');
    }
    else {


        $scope.logObj = {
            Username: 'hass',
            Password: '',
            session: $rootScope.session,
            loginUser: $rootScope.loginUser

        };

        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            if ($scope.logObj.Username == 'hassaan' && $scope.logObj.Password == 'hassaan') {
                $rootScope.loginUser.username = $scope.logObj.Username;
                $rootScope.loginUser.password = $scope.logObj.Password;
                $rootScope.loginUser.loginDateTime = new Date();
                $rootScope.loginUser.loginTrue = true;
                sessionStorage.setItem('storedInfo', JSON.stringify($rootScope.loginUser));
                $location.path('/home');
            }
        }

    }

}])
```

**Any guidance to resolve the problem?**

Comment: You can't share `sessionStorage` between tabs

Comment: You probably should not be implementing security related functionality by yourself, and certainly not using a client-side framework. How are your users authenticated? What is your back-end solution?

Comment: this is just dummy, in real scenario a service will be calling the authentication. Here i need to get ideas related maintaining session  as i mentioned session storage is not available across tabs

Comment: Session storage is scoped to a particular tab/window and it is not shared between browser tabs. If you need to share something between two tabs or windows, you need to use localStorage  or a Cookie.

Comment: And your back-end solution does not support sessions? See, the problem for you is not that for example local storage "will be available for next time", but that whatever solution you choose needs to be tied to the browser session issued by the web server, or something to the same effect, because that's the scope you say you want, is it not?

Comment: @OskarLindberg 1 thing which i could do is to make a factory or service and save the current session statistics with expiration time  and at the next time when user come first i could check the time period, if it returns false then i could re-initialize the session.
the problem with this logic is it will cause a post to server and call the response. I only want to save time in client-side session rather than server posted

Comment: What standard frameworks tend to do is issue a session cookie upon the first request and then re-use it. Checking that would obviously not require any round trip back to the server. To be more secure though, your data should be tied not just to a session, but to an *authenticated session*. This is to prevent things like [Session Fixation Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation). This is getting out of hand for the comments field though, and I still don't get your attempted solution quite.

Comment: security and session management should be backend logic and not UI. To route to a login page in case of a missing session should also be a backend logic and not UI. Otherwise, it can be very easily bypassed.